# Why isn't my for-loop printing in the second loop?

Tags: c, arrays, string, for-loop, stdin

I made a for loop that stores names in a array that the user selects it's size however when the for-loop runs it skips the second `printf` statement.

```
int NumToDelete;
printf("How much employees do you want to remove?\n");
scanf(" %d", &NumToDelete);
char Name[NumToDelete][25];
for(int i = 0; i < NumToDelete; i++)
{
    fgetc(stdin);      //To stop the program from doing
    printf("Name: ");  //something like this: Name:Name:
    fgets(Name[i], 25, stdin);
}
```

The prompts and user input should look something like this (if `NumToDelete` is 3):

```
Name: Ahmed
Name: John
Name: Bob
```

But instead, after I enter the name "Ahmed", I have to enter the second name "John" before the code displays the "Name:" prompt again. So the text in the console ends up looking like this:

```
Name: Ahmed
John
Name: Bob
```

The names being the user input. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should print the contents of your array of names after the loop and see what you get.  Then you'd see why the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57540672/15168) by [CFLS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9336098/cfls) is correct.

Comment: The names are not printed by the code. The code print "Name: " and everything after that is typed in the console.

Comment: Post _exactly_ what was entered.

Comment: Ugh, VLAs. Test your program with `NumToDelete` equal to 335544 or larger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that fgetc should be outside of the for-loop. Try this code:

```
int NumToDelete;
printf("How much employees do you want to remove?\n");
scanf(" %d", &NumToDelete);
fgetc(stdin);
char Name[NumToDelete][25];
for(int i = 0; i < NumToDelete; i++)
{
    printf("Name: ");
    fgets(Name[i], 25, stdin);
}
```

The reason for this is that `fgets` consumes the trailing newline from its input, but not the leading newline.